# Entrust package and displaying roles expecting array but receives object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Recently I've started to learn Larave but from version 4.2. I've followed other users from SO advice to dump v4.2 and start with 5.4. So I did this.

I've installed laravel 5.4.* and Entrust package and trying to build simple ACL cms.

Everything is fine so far but when I try to `Edit` some role I've got error

> in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

The problem is in the blade here:

```
@foreach($permission as $value)
    <label>{{ Form::checkbox('permission[]', $value->id, in_array($value->id, $rolePermissions) ? true : false, array('class' => 'name')) }}
    {{ $value->display_name }}</label>
    <br/>
@endforeach
```

This is the Controller function

```
 public function edit($id)
 {
     $role = Role::find($id);
     $permission = Permission::get();
     $rolePermissions = DB::table("permission_role")
                          ->where("permission_role.role_id",$id)
                          ->pluck('permission_role.permission_id','permission_role.permission_id');

     return view('roles.edit',compact('role','permission','rolePermissions'));
 }
```

Generally I know what the error means. It means that the query return collection- object but I can't understand how to fix this.

Comment: Whatever you are doing there is also package for handling permissions, if this is simple site use policies / gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use `->toArray()` on collection object.

---

Text below is out of the scope of this question.

You can trim your controller a bit.

```
 public function edit(Role $role) // in route file you want to do Get::route('roles/{role}/edit'...)
 {
     //role should have relation M-M so you can access "permissions" like $role->permissions

     return view('roles.edit')->withRole($role);
 }
```

If you follow all the conventions you should define M-M relationships as follows:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'your pivot table', 'role_id', 'permission_id');
}
```

Comment: Okay, with `->toArray()` on `$rolePermission` query is working. Thank's is so simple.

Comment: When I tried above function I've got `permission undefined` error

Comment: Do you have relationships on models defined?

Comment: Oh, no. `Role` and `Permissions` models are still empty.

Comment: I'm following their instructions: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust and there is also empty

Comment: Oh I see, good job; forget my edits regarding models, use whatever entrust instructs you I was just worried you are going to do crazy-ivan DB selects in controller (avoid at all costs!).

Comment: Okay, thank's a lot for the help. I'll get to relations in Models .. eventually.